# Can map() take functions with multiple inputs?

Tags: r, function, dictionary, purrr

I want to loop glm/lm over multiple outcomes and predictors while stratified by groups. nest() and map() functions from purrr package seems to provide an elegant solution to stratification analysis. However, when I use a customized function which takes multiple input, map() doesn't seem to work.

In almost all the tutorials on map() from purrr I have seen,regression model examples are static -- the dependent and independent variables are explicitly defined in the function. Because I want to loop over dozens of outcomes and predictors, I am trying to write a lm() function that can iterate over different combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# example data set
set.seed(20)
df <- data.frame(
  out = rep(c(0,1),5,replace=TRUE),
  pre = sample(c(1:4),10,replace = TRUE),
  var1 = sample(c(1:2),10,replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(c(1:50),10,replace = TRUE),
  group = sample(c(1:2),10,replace = TRUE)
)

explicit_fun<-function(data){
  glm(out ~ pre + var1 + var2, data=data, family = binomial())
}

input_fun<-function(data, outcome, predictor, covariate){
  glm(as.formula(paste(outcome,"~",predictor,"+",paste(covariate,collapse = "+"))),data=data,family = binomial())
}

# nesting the data set
df_by_group<-df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  nest()
```

it works fine with the explicit function

```
models <- df_by_group%>%
  mutate(mod=purrr::map(data,explicit_fun))
models <- models%>%
  mutate(
         glance_glm=purrr::map(mod,broom::glance),
         tidy_glm=purrr::map(mod,broom::tidy),
         augment_glm=purrr::map(mod,broom::augment)
         )
unnest(models,data)
unnest(models,glance_glm,.drop = TRUE)%>% View()
unnest(models,tidy_glm) %>% View()
```

it stops working when using the function has multiple inputs

```
models<-df_by_group%>%
mutate(mod=purrr::map(data,input_fun(data=.,outcome="out",predictor="pre",covariate=c("var1","var2"))))
```

I expect the input_fun would work the same as the explicit_fun, but I received the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Can't convert a `glm/lm` object to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `map()`. Right now, you are calling a function in the second parameter, not passing a function. The quickest way to fix this is to use the formula syntax to create a function. Try

```
models <- df_by_group%>%
  mutate(mod=purrr::map(data, ~input_fun(data=.,outcome="out",predictor="pre",covariate=c("var1","var2"))))
```

This delays the evaluation of `input_fun` till the map actually happens and properly fills in the `.` value.